# TypeError: (0 , ln.useState) is not a function | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

Tengo un proyecto que desarrolle en React y desde mi computadora funciona perfectamente. Ahora cuando lo subo a github pages o vercel me da este error en la consola y no carga absolutamente nada (queda en blanco):

```
TypeError: (0 , ln.useState) is not a function
at mn (App.js:11:39)
at il (react-dom.production.min.js:157:137)
at Yi (react-dom.production.min.js:267:460)
at Pu (react-dom.production.min.js:250:347)
at Nu (react-dom.production.min.js:250:278)
at ju (react-dom.production.min.js:250:138)
at bu (react-dom.production.min.js:243:163)
at hu (react-dom.production.min.js:237:175)
at es (react-dom.production.min.js:285:27)
at react-dom.production.min.js:289:301
```

Ya lo resolvi, agrego la solucion por si alguien le sirve:

Al usar los "atajos" de VS Code a la hora de importar useState o useEffect, VS Code los importa desde "react/cjs/react.development" cambiar esto y que quede directamente from "react".

Comment: La solución no va en la pregunta sino en la zona de respuestas

Comment: ¿Cuales atajos? saludos